# Compute/estimate grid from values

Tags: matlab, grid, interpolation

I have some values and the location of them on a grid.
e.g.

```
V1=1
V2=2
V3=4
...
```

I know the location of those values on a fixed spaced grid.
e.g.

```
V2 x x V1 x V3
x  x x x  x x 
V5 x x x V4 V6
```

Now what I need is to interpolate the missing values x. 
e.g. the first row

```
2 1.66 1.33 1 2.5 4
```

It's a two dimensional problem. Any hints how I can efficiently solve it? The amount of V may vary.
Thanks

Comment: If it's not a model-fitting type problem then [a simple search of the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple interpolation of irregular grid problem. `meshgrid` is useful.

```
x = [4,1,6,5,1,6];
y = [1,1,1,3,3,3];
v = [1,2,4,2,4,5];

[xq,yq] = meshgrid(1:max(x), 1:max(y));
vq = griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq);
```

You need to explicitly define the x- and y- positions (this case row and column numbers) of your V data. Then use `meshgrid` to generate a grid (this case the matrix itself). Then use `griddata` to interpolate the data over the grid that you just created. `vq` is the resulting matrix you want.